# centering UILabel in UINavigationBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, uinavigationbar

I have a UINavigationBar and have the leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem set. The leftbar is set as:

```
UIButton *backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [backButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton] autorelease];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myButton;
```

and the rightbarbutton is set as:

```
UIButton *doneBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
 UIImage *doneButtonImage = nil;
        doneButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"done.png"];
        [doneBtn setImage:doneButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
  doneBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:doneBtn];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = doneBarButtonItem;
```

the width of back is 23px and done is 72px, so they're not equal. Now the issue is I have a label that I want to be in the center all the time.. and I want to clip the text if the text in the label is too long that it interferes with the right bar button. here's how I set it up:

```
titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    titleLabel.text = self.pageTitle; // Can't change
    titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    titleLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
    titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Narrow" size:30.0]; 
    titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6 alpha:1.0];
    titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
    [titleLabel sizeToFit];
    titleLabel.frameHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frameHeight;


 self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

However this doesn't center the title.. How can I do so?

Comment: just manually set the x value in the frame to whatever makes it looks centered to you.

Comment: Or use a toolbar instead and add flexible space items in between everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest first count the width of self.pageTitle 
then accordingly set the position of titleLabel.I prefer this:-

```
titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
titleLabel.text = self.pageTitle; // Can't change

**CGSize maximumTitleLabelSize = CGSizeMake(200,40);//Set maximum width that an self.pageTitle can have.
CGSize expectedLabelSize = [titleLabel.text titleLabel.font 
                                            constrainedToSize:maximumTitleLabelSize
                                                lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
//adjust the label the the new width.
CGRect newFrame = titleLabel.frame;
newFrame.size.width = expectedLabelSize.width;
titleLabel.size.width = newFrame.size.width;**    
if(titleLabel.size.width==100)
{
titleLabel.frame = cgRectMake(85,5,titleLabel.size.width,30);
}
else if(titleLabel.size.width==200)
{
titleLabel.frame = cgRectMake(36,5,titleLabel.size.width,30);
}

titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
titleLabel.clipsToBounds = YES;
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 1;
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"PTSans-Narrow" size:30.0]; 
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.6 alpha:1.0];
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[titleLabel sizeToFit];
titleLabel.frameHeight = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frameHeight;

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

Try this.It will help you.Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest solution, use the `sizeToFit` method before adding it to the `titleView`:

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
titleLabel.text = @"My Title";
titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17.0f];
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[titleLabel sizeToFit];

self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use NavigationItem to add left and right bar button, instead use addsubview method to add custom buttons for navigation bar.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tool bar to add multiple buttons to ur navigation bar.

```
   // create a toolbar to have two buttons in the right
UIToolbar* tools = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 133, 44.01)];

// create the array to hold the buttons, which then gets added to the toolbar
NSMutableArray* buttons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:3];

// create a standard "add" button
UIBarButtonItem* bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]`enter code here`
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:NULL];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// create a spacer
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil];
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// create a standard "refresh" button
bi = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh target:self action:@selector(refresh:)];
bi.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
[buttons addObject:bi];
[bi release];

// stick the buttons in the toolbar
[tools setItems:buttons animated:NO];

[buttons release];

// and put the toolbar in the nav bar
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:tools];
[tools release];
```

Answer (score 0):

you just use this code its work fine try it

```
UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 5, 190, 30)];
titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
titleLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
titleLabel.text =@"My Wish List"; 
titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Copperplate" size:16.0];
titleLabel.minimumFontSize = 10;
titleLabel.autoresizingMask=UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.navigationItem.titleView = titleLabel;
[titleLabel release];
```

i use this code in my project also.......
:-)